# windows c++ thread waiting on queue data-push

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, events, queue

My program is setup as follows:
There is a thread-safe queue class, one thread pushing data onto it while sitting in an infinite loop and a second thread popping data off of it while sitting in an infinite loop. I am trying to think of a way to use windows events, or some other mechanism to make the thread_1 (below), wait in the infinite while loop and only iterate when the queue depth is greater than or equal to 1.

```
class thread-safe_Queue
{
 public:
  push();
  pop();
};

DWORD thread_1()
{
 while(1)
 {
  // wait for thread-safe queue to have data on it
  // pop data off
  // process data
 }
}

DWORD thread_2()
{
 while(1)
 {
  // when data becomes available, push data onto thread-safe queue
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might do the trick. Derive class Event and overload the Process() function.

```
#include <process.h> // Along with all the normal windows includes

//*********************************************
using namespace os;

Mutex globalQueueMutex;

class QueueReader : public Event
{
public:
    virtual void Process()
    {
      // Lock the queue
      Locker l(globalQueueMutex);
      // pop data off
      // process data
      return; // queue will automatically unlock
    }
};

QueueReader myQueueReader;

//*********************************************
// The queue writer would have functions like :
void StartQueueReader()
{
    Thread(QueueReader::StartEventHandler, &myQueueReader);
}
void WriteToQueue()
{
    Locker l(globalQueueMutex);
    // write to the queue
    myQueueReader.SignalProcess(); // tell reader to wake up
}
// When want to shutdown
void Shutdown()
{
    myQueueReader.SignalShutdown();
}
```

Here are the classes that perform the magic.

```
namespace os {

// **********************************************************************
/// Windows implementation to spawn a thread.
static uintptr_t Thread (void (*StartAddress)(void *), void *ArgList)
{
  return _beginthread(StartAddress, 0, ArgList);
}

// **********************************************************************
/// Windows implementation of a critical section.
class Mutex
{
public:
  // Initialize section on construction
  Mutex() { InitializeCriticalSection( &cs_ ); }
  // Delete section on destruction
  ~Mutex() { DeleteCriticalSection( &cs_ ); }
  // Lock it
  void lock() { EnterCriticalSection( &cs_ ); }
  // Unlock it
  void unlock() { LeaveCriticalSection( &cs_ ); }

private:
  CRITICAL_SECTION cs_;
}; // class Mutex

/// Locks/Unlocks a mutex
class Locker
{
public:
  // Lock the mutex on construction
  Locker( Mutex& mutex ): mutex_( mutex ) { mutex_.lock(); }
  // Unlock on destruction
  ~Locker() { mutex_.unlock(); }
private:
  Mutex& mutex_;
}; // class Locker

// **********************************************************************
// Windows implementation of event handler
#define ProcessEvent  hEvents[0]
#define SetTimerEvent hEvents[1]
#define ShutdownEvent hEvents[2]

/// Windows implementation of events
class Event
{
  /// Flag set when shutdown is complete
  bool Shutdown;
  /// Max time to wait for events
  DWORD Timer;
  /// The three events  - process, reset timer, and shutdown
  HANDLE hEvents[3];

public:
  /// Timeout is disabled by default and Events assigned
  Event( DWORD timer = INFINITE) : Timer(timer)
  {
    Shutdown = false;
    ProcessEvent = CreateEvent( NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL );
    SetTimerEvent = CreateEvent( NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL );
    ShutdownEvent = CreateEvent( NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL );
  }

  /// Close the event handles
  virtual ~Event()
  {
    CloseHandle(ProcessEvent);
    CloseHandle(SetTimerEvent);
    CloseHandle(ShutdownEvent);
  }

  /// os::Thread calls this to start the Event handler
  static void StartEventHandler(void *pMyInstance)
    { ((Event *)pMyInstance)->EventHandler(); }
  /// Call here to Change/Reset the timeout timer
  void ResetTimer(DWORD timer)  { Timer = timer; SetEvent(SetTimerEvent); }
  /// Set the signal to shutdown the worker thread processing events
  void SignalShutdown() { SetEvent(ShutdownEvent); while (!Shutdown) Sleep(30);}
  /// Set the signal to run the process
  void SignalProcess() { SetEvent(ProcessEvent); }

protected:
  /// Overload in derived class to process events with worker thread
  virtual void Process(){}
  /// Override to process timeout- return true to terminate thread
  virtual bool Timeout(){ return true;}

  /// Monitor thread events
  void EventHandler()
  {
    DWORD WaitEvents;
    while (!Shutdown)
    {
      // Wait here, looking to be signaled what to do next
      WaitEvents = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, hEvents, FALSE, Timer);

      switch (WaitEvents)
      {
        // Process event - process event then reset for the next one
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
          Process();
          ResetEvent(ProcessEvent);
          break;

        // Change timer event - see ResetTimer(DWORD timer)
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
          ResetEvent(SetTimerEvent);
          continue;

        // Shutdown requested so exit this thread
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2:
          Shutdown = true;
          break;

        // Timed out waiting for an event
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
          Shutdown = Timeout();
          break;

        // Failed - should never happen
        case WAIT_FAILED:
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }


};

} // namespace os
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one (I assume you are familiar with events mechanism).

1.

```
thread_safe_Queue::push(something)
{
// lock the queue
...
// push object
// Signal the event
SetEvent(notification);

// unlock the queue
}
```

2.

```
thread_safe_Queue::pop(something)
{
WaitForSingleObject(notification);
// lock the queue
...
// get object
// reset the event
if (queue is empty)
  ResetEvent(notification);

// unlock the queue
}
```

3. thread_1 just tries to pop the object and handle it. As something is pushed, the event is enabled, so `pop` can be successfully called. Otherwise it will wait inside `pop`. Actually you can use other synchronizing objects like mutexes or critical sections instead of the events in this case.

UPDATE. External events:
thread 1:

```
void thread_1()
  {
  while(1)
    {
    WaitForSingleObject(notification);
    if (!pop(object))  // pop should return if there are any objects left in queue
      SetEvent(notification);    
    }
  }
```

thread_2

```
void thread_2()
  {
  while(1)
    {
    // push the object and than signal event
    ResetEvent(notification)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would prefer the events to be outside the class, and inside the thread entry point functions. The reason is there is a second event the threads wait on as well. That is when the user wants to end the program, and thus end the infinite while loop. When this happens, the user will send a command to close the program, the push thread will stop listening for data and close, and the push thread will stop waiting for the thread to have data in it, and will close as well.

Comment: You can do the same with external events. I updated the answer above.

Comment: didn't you mean for thread1 to call reset and thread 2 to call set in the external version? Also, How are you avoiding a deadlock in this scenario: 1. thread1 fails to pop. 2. thread2 calls set. 3. thread1 calls reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named events. Each thread would call CreateEvent passing in the same name. Then use WaitForMultipleObjects to wait for either queue related event or end program event. The pop thread would wait on queue_has_data and end_program events. The push thread would wait on data_available and end_program events and set the queue_has_data event when it puts something into the queue.